# crud actions into a module causing stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

I am trying to create a module which houses the standard crud functions. whether this can be done, is wise, stand practice, or not, i would like to find out for myself. So far I have created the standard get requests no problem. However I am trying to implement a create action and am encountering a 'stack level too deep error'.

```
class FlagsController < ApplicationController
  include CrudConcern

  before_action lambda { crud_index(Flag.all) }, only: :index
  before_action lambda { crud_new(Flag.new) }, only: :new
  before_action lambda { crud_create(Flag.new, flags_path) }, only: :create


  def create
  end  

end
```

crud module

```
  def crud_create(model, route)
    variable = model(params)
    if variable.save 
        flash[:notice] = "Saved!"
        redirect_to route
    else
        flash[:error] = "Try again"
        render :new 
    end
  end
```

Why would this occur? Is there a way around it? There is a Gem called Crudify which offers this so i assume it can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing in an instance of a model, rather than the model class your method expects.  I think you mean the following instead:

```
# in controller
before_action lambda { crud_create(Flag, flags_path) }, only: :create

# in crud module
def crud_create(model, route)
  variable = model.new(params) # change is here
  if variable.save 
    flash[:notice] = "Saved!"
    redirect_to route
  else
    flash[:error] = "Try again"
    render :new 
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

It may be also a redirect loop. `flags_path` may be hitting the same `create` method (as opposed to the index), which will continually hit the `crud_create` `before_action`, causing the `stack level too deep` error. Try changing the redirect to test :)

To avoid hitting `create` again, you may have to set the status to 303. From the APIDock entry for `redirect_to`:

> If you are using XHR requests other than GET or POST and redirecting
>   after the request then some browsers will follow the redirect using
>   the original request method. This may lead to undesirable behavior
>   such as a double DELETE. To work around this you can return a 303 See
>   Other status code which will be followed using a GET request.

example: `redirect_to route, status: 303`

Comment: it still gives the same error. I tried this variation but to no avail.